# Cannot access a scoped thread local variable without calling `set` first

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and puzzled by the error caused by the following code:

```
use std::{io::Result, rc::Rc};
use clap::Parser;
use futures_lite::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, StreamExt};
use glommio::{
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
    prelude::*,
};

async fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) -> Result<()> {
    let mut buf = [0u8, 1];
    loop {
        let b = stream.read(&mut buf).await?;
        if b == 0 {
            break;
        } else {
            stream.write(&buf).await?;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(short, long, default_value_t = 1)]
    cpu: usize,
    #[arg(short, long, default_value = "0.0.0.0:8888")]
    bind_address: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let args = Args::parse();
    let listener = Rc::new(TcpListener::bind(args.bind_address)?);

    let executor = LocalExecutorBuilder::new(Placement::Fixed(args.cpu)).make()?;
    executor.run(async {
        while let Some(stream) = listener.incoming().next().await {
            let stream = stream.unwrap();
            spawn_local(handle_connection(stream)).detach();
        }
    });

    Ok(())
}
```

I'm trying to write a single-threaded server that can handle multiple connections with glommio. The program fails in a cryptic runtime error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'cannot access a scoped thread local variable without calling `set` first'
```

Any ideas what is causing it and how to fix it? I'm assuming that it's caused by not joining on the tasks anywhere, but I could be wrong here. I'm also not exactly sure how to idiomatically do that.

EDIT: Looks like the following minimal code already reproduces the error:

```
use std::{io::Result, rc::Rc};
use glommio::net::TcpListener;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let listener = Rc::new(TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8888")?);
    Ok(())
}
```

What the heck is wrong here then?

EDIT 2: I assumed this problem might have something to do with the listener not being owned by an executor, since I'm guessing it's created outside the executor, so there's no event loop. If I move the listener creation inside the `executor.run` call, then the code works just fine.

Would still be happy if someone clarified to me exactly why the original code won't work.

Comment: You might need to turn on a deeper backtrace to get more information here.

Comment: `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run`

Comment: It's actually failing at the TcpListener::bind. Any ideas?